# Datepicker standard minimal 30 days and 2 months visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've got a datepicker but I want to have two things changed:

*Only allow to select the enddate 30 days ahead of the startdate

*The visible datepicker to show 2 months because you can't select the enddate in the same month as the startdate.

*The clear function doesn't seem to be working

Thanks for your help.

Sorry I'm little bit newbie.

```
export class calendar extends field {

    init() {

        this.range = this.$.data('range')
        this.readonly = this.$.data('readonly')
        this.clicks = 0
        this.ts = 0
        this.ts_end = 0
        this.date = ''
        this.date_end = ''

        if( ! this.readonly ) {

            $('.rz-calendar .rz-days li', this.$).on('click rz-calendar:pick', (e) => this.day_click(e, true))
            $('.rz-calendar .rz-days li', this.$).on('mouseenter mouseleave', (e) => this.day_hover(e))
            $('.rz-calendar-clear', this.$).on('click', () => this.clear( true ))

            this.$.on('rz-calendar:change', () => this.change())
            this.$.on('rz-calendar:clear', () => this.clear())

        }

        $('.rz-calendar-nav a', this.$).on('click', (e) => this.nav(e))

        this.selected()

    }

    selected() {

        if( ! this.$.hasClass('rz-calendar-end') ) {

            let ts_start = $('.rz-calendar-ts', this.$).val()
            let ts_end = $('.rz-calendar-ts-end', this.$).val()

            if( ts_start.length && ts_end.length ) {
                $(`.rz-days li[data-timestamp="${ts_start}"]`).trigger('click')
                $(`.rz-days li[data-timestamp="${ts_end}"]`).trigger('click')
            }

        }

    }

    change() {

        $('.rz-calendar-ts', this.$).val( this.ts )
        $('.rz-calendar-ts-end', this.$).val( this.ts_end )

        $('.rz-calendar-date-start', this.$).val( this.date )
        $('.rz-calendar-date-end', this.$).val( this.date_end )

        this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:changed')

        if( ! this.range || this.ts_end ) {
            this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:satisfied', {
                ts: this.ts,
                ts_end: this.ts_end,
                date: this.date,
                date_end: this.date_end,
            })
        }

        this.collect()

    }

    day_hover(e) {

        if ( this.clicks == 1 ) {
            let $e = $( e.currentTarget )
            if( ! ( $e.hasClass('rz--not-available') || $e.hasClass('rz--temp-disabled') ) || $e.hasClass('rz--temp-active') ) {
                this.set_between_range( this.ts, $e.data('timestamp') )
            }
        }

    }

    set_between_range( from, to ) {

        $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li', this.$)
            .removeClass('rz--in-between')
            .filter(function() {
                let current = $(this).data('timestamp')
                return current > from && current < to
            })
            .addClass('rz--in-between')

    }

    day_click( e, is_click ) {

        let day = $( e.currentTarget )

        if(
            (
                day.hasClass('rz--not-available') ||
                day.hasClass('rz--temp-disabled') ||
                day.hasClass('rz--day-disabled') ||
                day.hasClass('rz--from-day')
            ) &&
            ! day.hasClass('rz--temp-active')
        ) {
            return
        }

        is_click = is_click || false

        let ts_picked = day.data('timestamp')
        let date_picked = day.data('date')

        $('.rz-calendar-actions', this.$).addClass('rz-visible')

        // single
        if( ! this.range ) {

            this.clear_days()
            // $('.rz-calendar-ts', this.$).val( date_picked )
            day.addClass('rz--from-day rz--to-day rz--selected')

            this.ts = ts_picked
            this.date = date_picked

            this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:change').trigger('rz-calendar:change')

            this.collect()

        }
        // range
        else{

            this.clicks += 1

            // start
            if( this.clicks == 1 ) {

                this.ts = ts_picked
                this.date = date_picked

                this.day_leave()
                this.disable_previous_dates()
                this.disable_next_dates_after_unavailable()
                this.enable_departing()

                this.$.addClass('rz-calendar-start')
                day.addClass('rz--from-day rz--selected')

                if( is_click ) {
                    this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:change')
                }

            }

            // end
            else if( this.clicks == 2 ) {

                this.ts_end = ts_picked
                this.date_end = date_picked

                this.disable_day_leave()
                this.disable_next_dates()
                this.set_between_range( this.ts, this.ts_end )

                this.$.removeClass('rz-calendar-start').addClass('rz-calendar-end')
                day.addClass('rz--to-day rz--selected')

                if( is_click ) {
                    this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:change')
                }

            }

            this.collect()

        }

    }

    day_leave() {
        $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li', this.$).on('mouseleave', () => {
            $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li', this.$).removeClass('rz--in-between')
        })
    }

    disable_day_leave() {
        $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li', this.$).off('mouseleave')
    }

    disable_next_dates() {

        let _this = this

        $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li[data-timestamp]', this.$)
            .filter(function() {
                let ts_current = $(this).data('timestamp')
                return ts_current > _this.ts_end
            })
            .addClass('rz--temp-disabled')
            .removeClass('rz--temp-active')

    }

    disable_next_dates_after_unavailable() {

        let _this = this
        let has_unavailable = false

        $('.rz-calendar-month ul li', this.$).filter(function() {

            let day = $(this)
            let current = day.data('timestamp')

            // fix for single day unavailable, having start and end
            if( current > _this.ts && day.hasClass('rz--unavailable-start') ) {
                has_unavailable = true
                return
            }

            if( day.hasClass('rz--unavailable-ends') && current > _this.ts ) {
                has_unavailable = true
            }

            return ( current < _this.ts ) || has_unavailable

        })
        .addClass('rz--temp-disabled')

    }

    disable_previous_dates() {

        let _this = this

        $('.rz-calendar-month .rz-days li', this.$).filter(function() {
            let day = $(this)
            let ts_current = day.data('timestamp')
            return ( ts_current < _this.ts )
        })
        .addClass('rz--temp-disabled')

    }

    enable_departing() {

        let _this = this

        let next_unavailable = $('.rz-calendar-month ul li.rz--unavailable-start', this.$)
            .filter(function( index ) {
                let current = $(this).data('timestamp')
                return current > _this.ts
            }
        ).eq(0)

        next_unavailable.addClass('rz--temp-active')

    }

    clear_days() {

        this.$.removeClass('rz-calendar-start rz-calendar-end')
        $('.rz-calendar-month ul li', this.$).removeClass('rz--to-day rz--from-day rz--selected rz--in-between rz--temp-disabled rz--temp-active')

    }

    clear( is_click ) {

        is_click = is_click || false

        this.clear_days()

        this.clicks = 0

        $('.rz-calendar-actions', this.$).removeClass('rz-visible')

        this.ts = this.ts_end = this.date = this.date_end = ''
        this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:change')
        if( is_click ) {
            this.$.trigger('rz-calendar:cleared')
        }

        this.collect()

    }

    nav(e) {

        let element = $( e.currentTarget )

        let months = $('.rz-calendar-month', this.$).length
        let is_next = element.data('action') == 'next'

        let indexes = []
        $('.rz-calendar-month.rz-active', this.$).each(( index, element ) => {
            indexes.push( $( '.rz-calendar-month', this.$ ).index( element ) )
        })

        // first month
        if( ! is_next && indexes[0] == 0 ) {
            return
        }

        // last month
        if( is_next && indexes[ indexes.length - 1 ] + 1 >= months ) {
            return
        }

        let nav = $('.rz-calendar-nav', this.$)
        $('a', nav).removeClass('rz-disabled')

        // nav first
        if( ! is_next && indexes[0] == 1 ) {
            $('a[data-action="prev"]', nav).addClass('rz-disabled')
        }

        // nav last
        if( is_next && indexes[ indexes.length - 1 ] + 2 >= months ) {
            $('a[data-action="next"]', nav).addClass('rz-disabled')
        }

        $( '.rz-calendar-month', this.$ ).removeClass('rz-active')
        let new_index
        for ( let i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++ ) {

            new_index = indexes[i] + ( is_next ? +1 : -1 )
            $( '.rz-calendar-month', this.$ ).eq( new_index ).addClass('rz-active')

        }

    }

}
'''
```

Comment: Did I include all the code for the datepicker? Sorry for being bit a newb

Comment: See my website [link](http://citymonde.com). 
I would like something more like this: [link](https://www.theblueground.com/furnished-apartments-london-uk/london-soho-089)